Animating Kyle Robot in Unity (or any humanoid)
So, I recently discovered that when I try to record animations for Kyle Robot, it was never working - position and rotation appeared to be changing when I hit the Record button (in the Animator), but it never actually correctly created the keyframes.
Then someone online said you can’t animate humanoid models like that? Then, how do you animate them?
Anyway, once I changed it to Generic, it allowed me to record position and rotation changes. So I thought everything was going well.
But now, I’m trying to implement inverse kinematics (IK) with Kyle Robot, and apparently that requires a humanoid rig type. When I change it back to humanoid and press Play, Kyle is rendered halfway through the floor I’ve made for him, and is hunched up.

I’ve had friends try it, and they’re getting the same result. Additionally, I thought maybe it was just Robot Kyle, so I tried a Cyborg Chinese Warrior, and it does everything exactly the same.
I’m wondering if there’s been some sort of regression bug in Unity that messed up the Animation system, if the (15 or more) different tutorials I found are all wrong (seems unlikely), or if there’s something else wrong.
Any ideas?
Thanks,
G

I think its because you may have selected additive option in unity animator controller of the object. Open animator -> Layers -> Check all layers settings and see if you have selected additive in blending mode, change to override. For on point understanding of IK see https://youtu.be/SU2D0EO6Ctw
